# Дополнительная функциональность raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Пишу утилиту, которая позволяет запускать определенные скрипты на удаленных машинах. В итоге, получается что-то вроде ограниченной командой строки. На данный момент я использую такую конструкцию:

```
exec_script = raw_input('\033[1;37mcmd> \033[1;m')
```

Однако в таком варианте кучу неудобств. Например, нельзя использовать клавишу ↑ для просмотра предыдущих команд. Можно ли это осуществить в python 2.7?

Comment: Помимо упомяутого в ответе, всегда можно работать напрямую через каких-нибудь tty и termios, например, и самому реализовать всё что надо. Или просто взять ncurses

Comment: Посмотрите на [`prompt_toolkit` библиотеку](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prompt_toolkit) (например, используется в IPython 5+).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться модулем [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html). Достаточно просто импортировать его в начале скрипта:

```
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-

import readline

while True:
    s = raw_input('\033[1;37mcmd> \033[1;m')
    if s == 'quit':
        print 'Bye bye!'
        break
    print 'Echo: "%s"' % s
```

Comment: Если Питон запущен в интерактивном режиме (REPL, `-i`), то `readline` модуль автоматически импортируется.